# What do I use to keep track of a number?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dieClass
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("How many times do you want to roll?");
        int rollamt = reader.nextInt();



        for (int i = 0; i < rollamt; i++)
        {
            int dice1 = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int dice2 = gen.nextInt(6) + 1; 
            int total = dice1 + dice2;
            int [] arrayDice = new int [rollamt];

            for (int r = 0; r < arrayDice.length; r++)
            {
                arrayDice[r] = total;
            }

          System.out.println("sum is " + total);
        }
    }
}
```

I was on to something but I give up. How do i keep track of how many times the sum of the two die was chosen?
A while loop ? (The result of the two die can only be between 2 and 12)

So for example I want to have a loop that will Add one  to its counter for its  assigned number

x = sum of two die

y = number of times

The output can be "the number x was rolled y times"

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  What is the exact task?

Comment: Roll two die an x amount of times and take the sum of the two die (which has numbers 1-6) then track how many times each number was rolled (the sum of the die)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your while loop, you simply have another array that holds a count of each possible roll.

You've already got the total, right here.

```
int total = dice1 + dice2;
```

Just add an array, outside of the loop to start a count:

```
int possibleRolls[]=new int[13]
```

and inside your loop:

```
possibleRolls[total]++;
```

When the loop is finished, you can check the indexes in the array to see how many each total was rolled.

Comment: Oh, wow tysm I understand now. So basically just use the total to add one into the cell

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Map that is a Map of the number to the number of times rolled.

```
java.util.Map<Integer, Integer> rollMap = new java.util.HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < rollamt; i++)
{
    int dice1 = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int dice2 = gen.nextInt(6) + 1; 
    int total = dice1 + dice2;

    Integer count = rollMap.get(total);
    if (null == count)
    {
        rollMap.put(total, Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
    else
    {
        rollMap.put(total, Integer.valueOf(count + 1));
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : rollMap.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println("Number " + entry.getKey()+ " was rolled " + entry.getValue() + "times")
}
```

Comment: I'm down-voting this answer because there is absolutely no reason to use a `Map` when an 11 element integer array is all that is required. I realize that this will work, but that doesn't mean it is a good answer.

Comment: @SeanBright I really don't think is deserves to be down voted. Yes I agree that in this case that an Array would suffice, but this still works and is a valid alternative answer and doesn't mean its a necessarily a bad answer either.

Comment: @JavaDevil, you could also use 11 separate `int`s to store the totals - would that be a bad answer?

Comment: @JavaDevil, and for that matter, why a `Map<Integer, Integer>` and not a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: @SeanBright You could also save each total in a csv file then read the file looking for the total you are interested in, whats your point, there are so many different ways to do to this, most of them horrible. Yes, 11 `ints` would be a bad answer, but that is not the same comparison between using a `Map` or `List` or an array. I'm not saying its the **best** answer, its just not worthy of a downvote imo.